# How to set the value for an external variable from the response via .subscribe()

Tags: angular, observable

I faced with difficulties for getting values from async queries using Observable in Angular 5

```
export class CustomComponent {
private external: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getContent() {
     return this.http.get('api/conten/get');
}


retrieve() {
    this.getContent().subscribe(content => {
        this.external = content;
        console.log(this.external) // here we get content that we expect
    });

    console.log(this.external); // there is 'undefined'
}
```

}

How can I set **external** variable with result from **getContent()**?
Probably there are other ways?
I guess this situation very frequent when we need to use response in code bellow
Please, give example how can I get value from response immediately after request(e.g. make request sync within the framework of Angular)

Comment: Code inside subscribe it's called asynchronously. So when you call `console.log(this.external)` the code in subscribe has not yet been executed, hence the value of this.external is still undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not explain how to get the value immediately below the code

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing things is correct.

The reason your second `console.log` prints `undefined` is simply because the `retrieve` function does not wait for your async operation (`getContent()`) to finish before moving on to the next line.

Here's a simplified timeline:

1. Execute `retrieve`
2. Execute `getContent`, oh, it's async, let's subscribe to it and **move on**
3. Print `this.external`    → `undefined`
4. When `getContent` returns (sometimes later), assign the returned value to `this.external`
5. Print `this.external`    → `correct value`

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer. Perhaps there is a way to get value from **getContent()** immediately after **.subscribe()** for using the **this.external** variable below the code?